# Windows crashes when I try to compress large .MOV file from iPhone

Tags: compression, video-conversion, quicktime

I have a 40 minute, 6 gigabyte .MOV file that I transferred from my iPhone to my PC. I need to upload the video to Youtube but the file is too large. When I try to compress the video, my computer will shut off when the process reaches 3 or 4 percent. This has happened in Windows Live Movie Maker, Riva FLV encoder, and VLC.

Any ideas on how I can get this file down to a reasonable size so I can upload it online?

Comment: I would guess either you're CPU's overheating or the compression scheme is somehow running out of storage.

Comment: why don't you try using some freeware transcoder, http://www.mediacoderhq.com/

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? and is it 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1):

try encoding with the task viewer open. take a look at the memory usage when the compression reaches 3-4% before the computer shuts down. While the said programs shouldn't shut your computer down perhaps your computer is running out of memory.